# Change in behaviour & generation of nullreference exception

Tags: c#

I made this program 2hr ago and it ran quit well when i confronted this to presaved .xls file. But when i closed that and started new instance,it started generating null refrence exception why??plz explain.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;




using System.IO;

using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace svchost
{

    class MainClass
    {
        Excel.Application oExcelApp;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainClass mc = new MainClass();
            while (true)
            {
                if (mc.chec())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RUNNING");

                    Thread.Sleep(4000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NOT RUNNING");

                    Thread.Sleep(8000);
                }

            }


        }
        public bool chec()
        {



            try
            {
                oExcelApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                Excel.Workbook xlwkbook = (Excel.Workbook)oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook;

                //****PROBLEM FROM HERE*********

            Console.WriteLine(xlwkbook.Name + "\n");
            ke kw = new ke(ref oExcelApp,ref xlwkbook);

            Console.WriteLine(xlwkbook.Author);

            xlwkbook = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            oExcelApp = null;
            System.GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine(ec);
            return false;

        }
        oExcelApp = null;

        System.GC.Collect();
        return true;
    }
}




class ke

{
    public ke(ref Excel.Application a1, ref Excel.Workbook b1)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)a1.ActiveSheet;
        Console.WriteLine(a1.ActiveWorkbook.Name + "\n" + ws.Name);
        Excel.Range rn;
        rn = ws.Cells.Find("657/07", Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
   Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Console.WriteLine(rn.Text);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Take a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and reformat your code please.

Comment: what line does the exception occur?

Comment: Is the 'line 1000' bit where the error happens?

Comment: no actually line thousand is preprocessor "# line  1000"

Comment: and in html it got retranslated

Answer (score 5):

Wow, a lot of scary things going on in there.

1. Don't ever write the line `GC.Collect()` unless you have an extremely good reason.  This is not one of those times.
2. The line `oExcelApp = null` accomplishes nothing.  I'm guessing this was "translated" from a VB script/app where you had to write `Set xxx = Nothing`, and then the discovery came that the GC is nondeterministic and that you could "fix" it with `GC.Collect()`.  Let the GC do its job, don't mess with it if you don't know what you're doing.
3. Catching the top-level `Exception` and eating it... not re-throwing, not wrapping, not logging, nothing.  In this case it should probably be a `finally`, with the `return true` inside the `try` block and `return false` after the `finally` block.
4. `ref` parameters in a method that doesn't need reference semantics for any reason.  Get rid of them.
5. Meaningless class and method names.  How are we supposed to understand what's going on here?
6. Never checking for `null` results, and this is undoubtedly why you're getting the exception.  I see several instances.  The first is after the line starting with `rn = ws.Cells.Find` - this method can return `null`.  The `ActiveWorkbook` property can also return `null`, and you pass this to the `ke` constructor which does not verify that the workbook is a valid reference.  Finally, `Marshal.GetActiveObject` can also return `null` and you never check to make sure that it succeeds.
7. Creating a class and using its constructor to do the same work that could be done in a single method.  I don't understand why the `ke` class even exists - it has no methods or properties!.  Give the method a proper name, remove that `ke` class and put it inside the same class that's doing the rest of the work.
8. Declaring variables and then assigning them on the next line.  I suppose this is more of a code style issue but again makes me think that this was some sort of automated translation from VB.  If you are assigning to variables immediately after declaring them, then put the declaration and assignment on the same line, `Range rn = ...`.
9. Usage of `Thread.Sleep`, presumably to prevent some sort of race condition - and not a reliable means of doing so.

Hopefully one of those things (probably #6) will lead you to a solution...

Comment: 1+2>-- I DON KNOW BUT ONCE 40'S OF EXCEL.EXE were running in taskmanager when i left the object . so i decided to destroy it manually.
3+4+5+7>. in actual the program is quite large and most of coding is still remaining ,at the same time i'm overloaded with error at initial stage.so i decided to ask u all guys.
6>actually the whole program is for tracing the specific number "657/07" & that's the key.
8>i applozise here because this code was written for better visiblity otherwise i had to keep on moving scrolling bars all the time.
9>ITS THE NECCESITY OTHER THAT WILL EAT MY WHOLE PROCESSOR

Comment: @peril brain: That will not happen if you use `Marshal.GetActiveObject`.  My guess is that you were originally creating a new Excel instance and not calling the `Quit()` method or setting `Visible = true` to make the app visible, which is why you get those orphaned processes in task manager.  If you then changed the construction to `Marshal.GetActiveObject`, you have to be aware that unlike `new Excel.Application` or `new ApplicationClass`, it will not start a new process, but **can** return `null`.  Fix the code - read one of the many tutorials on C# Excel interop.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public bool chec()
            {
                Excel.Application oExcelApp;


                try
                {

                    oExcelApp = (Excel.

Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); ;
                if (oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook != null)
                {
                    Excel.Workbook xlwkbook = (Excel.Workbook)oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook;


                    ke k = new ke(ref oExcelApp, ref xlwkbook);

                }


            }
            catch 
            {
                if (reg > 100) { } else { reg++; goto End; }//public static int reg=0;
                oExcelApp = null;

                /*Process[] ppo = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
                foreach(Process pppp in ppo)
                {
                  pppp.Kill();
                }*/

                End:
                return false;

            }

               finally{ oExcelApp = null;
                System.GC.Collect();}




            return true;
        }
    }
```